# Run Rasa bot on Azure Web App for Containers

Tags: azure, docker, rasa, azure-web-app-for-containers

I'm trying to make the Rasa default bot run in Azure Web App for Containers, but I get the following error:

```
2020-06-15T14:51:54.990Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 7 Minutes and 3 Seconds
2020-06-15T14:51:55.333Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2020-06-15T14:51:55.334Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 6939:5005 --name xxx-xxx-xxx_0_a01006f0 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=xxx-xxx-xxx -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=5005 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=xxx-xxx-xxx.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=2bc84f7540cae9fa0e13ee9b377da85ae072e0086c414b5b16e61e8788fd31c6 xxx/xxx-xxx:latest  

2020-06-15T14:51:55.335Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2020-06-15T14:51:58.326Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container xxx-xxx-xxx_0_a01006f0 for site xxx-xxx-xxx
2020-06-15T14:52:07.713Z ERROR - Container xxx-xxx-xxx_0_a01006f0 for site xxx-xxx-xxx has exited, failing site start
2020-06-15T14:52:07.735Z ERROR - Container xxx-xxx-xxx_0_a01006f0 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 5005, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2020-06-15T14:52:08.077Z INFO  - Stopping site xxx-xxx-xxx because it failed during startup.
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rasa/rasa:1.10.3

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN rasa train --domain domain.yml --data data --out models

EXPOSE 5005

CMD [ "rasa", "run", "-m", "models", "--enable-api" ]
```

Any idea where the port problem could come from? Should I enable container logs?

Comment: Yea, show us the container logs

Comment: In your `docker run` command, what does `-e PORT=5005` do?

Comment: You need to check if the image can run well locally and if the port is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the `rasa run` command.

The working version is `CMD ["run", "--enable-api" ]` for the last line in Dockerfile.